# Julia: sortslices: is it possible to pass the sort logic as a variable rather than a literal?

Tags: sorting, variables, julia, logic

```
unsorted = [3 5 9; 3 -6 11; 2 -4 8; 2 7 10]
sorted_1 = sortslices(unsorted, dims=1, by=x->(x[1],-abs(x[2])) )
```

gives as expected:

```
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 2   7  10
 2  -4   8
 3  -6  11
 3   5   9
```

I tried to put the third argument into a variable and pass it:

```
unsorted    = [3 5 9; 3 -6 11; 2 -4 8; 2 7 10]
sort_string = "by=x->(x[1],-abs(x[2]))"
sorted_2    = sortslices(output, dims=1, sort_string)
```

which gives:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching sortslices(::Array{Float64,2}, ::String; dims=1)
Closest candidates are:
  sortslices(::AbstractArray; dims, kws...) at multidimensional.jl:1751
```

Is there a syntax tweak that makes this work, or is there no solution like that?

(The reason I am trying to do this is that the sort logic I am coding depends on multiple user inputs, some of which are not binary.
I can do nested ifs to give 2 * 3 * 4 combinations each having a sortslices call, but it would be neater to concatenate the sort logic as a string which would involve only 2+3+4 if lines)

P.S. I am using Julia 1.5.3

Comment: Could you describe your problem more, give examples of what you do with the user input and how that becomes the sort_string expression? There are a lot of ways to do such things in Julia (and strings are usually not the best way), so it would help if we knew what kind of transformations you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use metaprogramming:

```
julia> sort_string = "x->(x[1],-abs(x[2]))";

julia> sorted_2 = sortslices(unsorted, dims=1, by=Meta.eval(Meta.parse(sort_string)))
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 2   7  10
 2  -4   8
 3  -6  11
 3   5   9
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.